# Baseline vs. progressive JPGs - differences that big?

Tags: jpeg

I am working on thermal images obtained with a FLIR VUE Pro infrared camera. The images come with a color palette applied in a 3x8bit RGB JPG format. When working with the images, I noticed a weird 16*16 pattern during my subsequent "calculations". One image I opened in GIMP and saved it again didn't have these patterns; so I investigated and found that the images directly from the camera come as baseline JPGs, while GIMP apparently automatically saves JPGs as progressive.

I compared the original image with the one re-saved in GIMP and really, I see a weird 16x16 pattern. This image shows the difference between the red channels of the baseline and the progressive image.
[image: pattern]

**My question:** Is it normal that the differences are in the magnitude of +-20 for 8bit images? Even if this pattern is not visible in the individual images, they make the outcome unusable if I use the baseline JPG. Why is it better to use the progressive JPG in this case?

Or am I completely wrong, and the mystery lies somewhere else?

Comment: Seems unlikely, although I couldn't tell for sure. Two reasons it's unlikely: JPEG works on 8x8 blocks, not 16x16, and if you look [here on page 120](https://www.w3.org/Graphics/JPEG/itu-t81.pdf) at how progressive JPEG works, it becomes clear that the DCT coefficient data is actually the same, binary identical, only entropy-coded and sent in a different order (and likely compressed a bit worse due to being in a different order). Note that any sentence which contains both "JPEG" and "calculation" is a bit suspect. JPEG is made for "looks OK", not for "provide data for calculation".

Comment: @Damon jep, that's what i also figured....I know, I never work with JPG, thats why I know not much about the underlying algorithms...a firmware update changed (unnoticed by our data provider) the settings from the usual 1-channel 14bit TIFF format to this d*mn JPG color palette thing, that's where the whole mess started...

Answer (score 1):

If you see something different with progressive and baseline, then something else is going on. Extended Sequential and Baseline are decoded identically—so much so that one wonders why JPEG created baseline at all.

In the case of progressive v baseline, all the lossy stuff is the same in the two. I suspect you have something going on differently with subsampling.

My virus detector goes crazy with your download links.

Comment: Sorry about the download links, I used the first file-upload service I found on Google....not the best one I guess! I removed them from my post.

Comment: And you are right about the subsampling; I read a little about it yesterday, and I think that would also explain the 16x16 pattern not being 8x8 as you might expect...